# How can I inject ViewDataDictionary or ModelStateDictionary into TagHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In razor views I can access model state object:

```
@ViewData.ModelState
```

How can i inject and access `ViewData` or `ModelState` objects in razor `TagHelper`? I tried the following, however the `ViewData` and `ModelState` are always null:

```
public class ModelStateTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject `IActionContextAccessor`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    }

    public class ModelStateTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public readonly IActionContextAccessor _accessor;

        public ModelStateTagHelper(IActionContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var modelState = _accessor.ActionContext.ModelState;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gives the model state, but what about ViewData?

Answer (score 20):

For those looking for the `ViewData` and not the `ModelState`, you can add the `ViewContext` to your `TagHelper`.

```
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var hasACertainKey = this.ViewContext.ViewData.ContainsKey("ACertainKey");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the answer we wanted

Comment: You can get the ModelState from the ViewContext here using ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState